# Block design: How to construct a 2-(16,6,2) design

Tags: combinatorial-designs

For my discrete mathematics class an exercise is to look at the following square and use it to construct a 2-(16,6,2) design:

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

9 10 11 12

13 14 15 16

So far my only inspiration has been to look at the amount of blocks b of our design, which should be 16 by the formula b = lambda (v choose t)/(k choose t) , but i don't know how to continue

Comment: For each point, think about the other points in its row and column.

Comment: I seeeeee! yes this solves my problem, thank you! Is there any "theoretical" way/ algorithm thingy to find this for any general t-(v,k,lambda) design that you used or is this just something you have to come up with by wit, intuition and experience?

Comment: I am just using my enormous wit, intuition and experience....

Comment: thank you senpai, for lending your aid

Comment: There is a lack of very general methods for constructing/proving non-existence of designs with given parameter sets.

Comment: Could you maybe provide a source for this? In my course we did not really discuss this besides from some basic necessary/sufficiant conditions for the case where t=2.